# Right bar button's frame starts in CGPoint(x:0, y:0)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to access the `midX` and `midY` properties of the bar button's frame to animate a view appearance from that point. To access them I'm using the following code:

```
 let barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
    let barButtonItemView = barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    let barButtonFrame = barButtonItemView?.frame

    print ("FRAME", barButtonFrame)
```

As you can see, there is a print statement at the end of the chunk, and it prints:

```
FRAME Optional((0.0, 0.0, 46.3333333333333, 44.0))
```

For some reason, the frame coordinates are both at `0`, so the view animation starts from the left top of the screen.

I've looked in many answers from here and almost all of them suggest the solution used above.

If you know why this happens, I would appreciate your help?

Comment: how are you adding your `barButtonItemView`? in your rightBarButtonItem ?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, you mean, how I get the `view`?

Comment: that view is the default view of UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: I have no experience with animating bar buttons, but does it have constraints?

Comment: @J.Doe, no I'm not animating the bar button itself. I just want to animate a view transition from the same point where the bar button is located.

Comment: @ReinierMelian, I think so